# pass the variable through SSH and run commands using the variable

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script

Below two files i have trying to execute and I have problem at echo "$application". I dont see get any output. How can I pass the variable through ssh and execute some commands using that variable.
It is successfully able to get the hostname and sshing to the server but the application is not getting passed to the command inside ssh.

ssh_test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
execommand(){
 ssh ${hostname} "application=$app1" <<'EOL'
  echo "$application"
  cd /opts/logs/${application}
EOL
}

source input.txt
execommand
```

input.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname="host1.server.com"
app1="home_loan"
export hostname
export app1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `bash` to the end of the initial command; ssh_test.sh should look like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
execommand(){
 ssh ${hostname} "application=$app1 bash" <<'EOL'
  echo "$application"
  cd /opts/logs/${application}
EOL
}

source input.txt
execommand
```

so that your commands are actually processed by the shell. Before, the shell wasn't even receiving them.

If you wish to disable the `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` warning that you will see, you may add the `-T` flag to the ssh command, and modify it like so:

```bsh
 ssh -T ${hostname} "application=$app1 bash" <<'EOL'
```